# Angular2 SELECT OPTION after pipe executes

Tags: angular

I have a select that is filtered using a pipe. The select looks like this:

```
<select ngControl="swimmerz" #swimmer="ngForm">
      <option *ngFor="let swimmer of swimmers | swimmerFilter:selectedClub.id:selectedSex" value= {{swimmer.id}}>{{swimmer.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

And the filter looks like this:

```
import {  PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
```

`import { Swimmer } from './swimmer';`

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'swimmerFilter'
})
export class SwimmerFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: Swimmer[], clubid: string, sex: string): Swimmer[] {
    clubid = clubid ? clubid.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;

    console.log('Filter ClubId parameter: ' + clubid);
    console.log('Filter Sex parameter: ' + sex);

    return clubid ? value.filter((swimmer: Swimmer) =>
        swimmer.clubid.toString() == clubid && swimmer.sex == sex) : value;
}
```

}

It works fine. On first run the first swimmer in the select is selected. On subsequent runs the options are filtered but there is no option selected. How can I force the first option to be selected after the pipe executes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not recommended to do the filtering in a pipe. Please take a look at [Pipes in Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe-)

The most important part is:

> The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend that you move filtering and sorting logic into the component itself.

So moving the logic to the component itself should also resolve your problem.